# Como imprimir QRCode na impressora Epson TM T20 VB.NET

Tags: .net, qrcode, basic

Estou tentando imprimir um *QR Code* na impressora Epson TM-T20 utilizando a linguagem VB.NET e ela está retornando diversos caracteres na bobina do cupom fiscal eletrônico, alguém poderia me auxiliar? Segue abaixo o código:

```
System.IO.File.Copy("C:\Users\TECNICO\Desktop\teste\qrcode.png", "COM2", True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matheus Ribeiro, por favor, veja esse exemplo (se você não tiver, é preciso fazer um cadastro no VBMania):

[S@T - IMPRIMIR QRCODE/CODIGO DE BARRAS](http://www.vbmania.com.br/index.php?modulo=detalhe&id=9455)

Exemplo de código para imprimir QRCODE com esc/pos em impressora epson não fiscal

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito, graças a sua ajuda consegui montar o cupom fiscal completo

Comment: Matheus Ribeiro, por favor, pode me pontuar? Agradecido.